# Using Newtonsoft.Json. How to do JObject.SelectToken when token name is "['token_name']"?

Tags: c#, json.net

Using Newtonsoft.Json I have the following JSON

`{"['token_name']":"0.00"}`

Trying

```
string s = "{\"['token_name']\":\"0.00\"}";
jsonObj = JObject.Parse(s);
myPJObject.SelectToken("['token_name']")
```

returns null. 
I've tried all kinds of variations like

```
myPJObject.SelectToken("[\"['token_name']\"]")
```

But could not find one that works.

How do I select this token?

Comment: Here is the some selectoken example.did you see this : https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SelectToken.htm

Comment: Sorry Bahtiyar, there was nothing there that could help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
jsonObj.SelectToken(@"['[\'token_name\']']")
```

`JObject` has `Path` property (you can try `jsonObj.First.Path` for your code) which in this case will return `"['[\'token_name\']']"` string, all is left is to handle the ecape `\` characters with [verbatim](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/verbatim) string prefix for example.

Answer (score 1):

Another possible solution is to use the indexer instead of `SelectToken` to handle this case:

```
var myPJObject = jsonObj["['token_name']"];
```

This works because the indexer does not use JsonPath syntax; it always takes the verbatim property name.

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/chNG3E